# Listener on database creation for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, role

I'm trying to achieve a set of functions/triggers to define database (catalog) level read-only role for every database created.

The way I thought of doing this is to create a listener (trigger/event trigger ?) on pg_database and when a new database is created It creates a new role, revoke all privileges (doing same for already created roles) on every other database and set the default read privileges for the newly created role.

**Question**: Is there a better approach to achieve this? If no, is there a way to run a function every time the command `CREATE DATABASE` run?

Comment: Have you looked into using a database template?

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE` uses `template1` database as default template for the new database. Whatever you have defined in `template1`, will be copied to the new database.
NOTE: Make a clean backup copy of template database before modifying it, in case you ever need to make a really empty database.

Comment: There are no triggers on database creation. Create Database is a special case that is not subject to the `ddl_command_start` filter. I'd look for an outside-the-database approach to your problem.